# Consistency of Scaled Sample Variance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be iid random variables. Consider the sample variance  $$S_n^2:=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \overline{X})^2$$ where $\overline{X}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is the sample mean. If $S_n^2$ is consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$; i.e.,  $S_n^2 \overset{P}{\to} \sigma^2$ as $n \to \infty$.  I wonder what would be the limit of the scaled sample variance; i.e., $\frac{S_n^2}{2} \overset{P}{\to} ?$.

On the one hand, by a [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), we know that $g(S_n^2) \to g(\sigma^2)$ for some continuous function $g$. Thus, it follows that $\frac{S_n^2}{2} \overset{P}{\to} \sigma^2/2.$
However, the point that I do not understand is that why not $\frac{S_n^2}{2} \overset{P}{\to} \frac{\sigma^2}{2^2}$?
The idea behind this thinking is that for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and a random variable $X$, ${\rm var}(a X) = a^2 {\rm var}(X)$---not $a {\rm var}(X)$.

Did I misunderstand the theorem or I made the mistake somewhere.

Comment: If $S_n^2 \overset{P}{\to} \sigma^2$ then $\frac{S_n^2}{2} \overset{P}{\to} \frac{\sigma_n^2}{2}$ while  $\left(\frac{S_n}{2}\right)^2 \overset{P}{\to} \left(\frac{\sigma_n}{2}\right)^2 =\frac{\sigma_n^2}{2^2} $ with the latter corresponding to ${\rm var}\left(\frac{X}{2}\right) = \frac1{2^2}{\rm var}\left(X\right)$

Comment: @Henry Thanks a lot. I think I got it.